# javascript textarea createTextNode()

Tags: javascript, html

I want to escape a string taken from a textarea using the createTextNode() method. Appending the TextNode to the textarea doesn't work.

```
function myFunc(){
    var str = document.getElementById("tarea").value;
    var chld = document.createTextNode(str); 
    var prnt = document.getElementById("tarea");
    prnt.appendChild(chld);
}
```

Comment: I'm expexting an escaped string. example: &lt;html&gt; for <html>

Comment: Sorry. Nothing happens. I enter <html> in the textarea, push the button that triggers the function, but the value of the textarea (i. e. <html>) stays the same.

Comment: With the above code, you'd see the text change (at least on Chrome, I haven't tried it cross-browser). You wouldn't see what you've said you want, but you'd see the text get appended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the browser do the escaping work for you, I'd probably use a temporary element for that, then use its `innerHTML` as the argument to `createTextNode`:

```js
function myFunc(){
  var prnt = document.getElementById("tarea");
  var str = prnt.value;
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
  prnt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(div.innerHTML));
}
myFunc();
```

```html
<textarea id="tarea">Testing & < ></textarea>
```

But minimally escaping HTML is very simple, you don't necessarily need to go whole-hog:

```
str = str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
```

(No need for `>`, it's fine as it is if you're not inside a tag.)

E.g.:

```js
function myFunc(){
  var prnt = document.getElementById("tarea");
  var str = prnt.value;
  str = str.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;");
  prnt.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
}
myFunc();
```

```html
<textarea id="tarea">Testing & < ></textarea>
```

---

Note that both of those **append**, because that's what your code was trying to do; they don't **replace** the content of the `textarea`. If you want to do that, set its `value` to `""` before appending the text node.

Comment: With the above function I still see no escaping work done by the browser. Maybe Im mistaken about createTextNode() doing that. I want to enable user input with special characters and prevent XSS.

Comment: @Msch: Take another look, the above does work. The initial content of the text area is `Testing & < >`. Then the function appends `Testing &amp; &lt; >` to it. (Append = **add** to end, not replace, see my note at the end of the answer.)